# How can I programmatically examine the stack in my Visual Studio extension?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, envdte, vs-extensibility

In a VS extension, assume that the code has just hit a breakpoint, and is in break mode. How can I programmatically examine the stack? Also, is there a way to figure out what the last executed statement was?

I haven't been able to find an advanced sample.  There are [hello-world type samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extensibility-hello-world?view=vs-2019) but they are mostly focused on adding/modifying UI elements in Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: The last executed statement is lost forever, but the current line (and possibly start column + end line/column) of the next statement to be executed are available through EnvDTE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to hook into the `EnvDTE.Events.DebuggerEvents.OnEnterBreakMode` event or equivalent to know when the process stops (and thus has a callstack). Be careful to keep a reference to `EnvDTE.Events.DebuggerEvents` otherwise it can be garbage collected and the connection to your event handler lost (normally this can't happen in C# but because of the way the EnvDTE event COM wrappers are implemented this is a known issue).

Once the debugger is in break mode, you can iterate `EnvDte.Debugger.CurrentThread.StackFrames` like so:

```
foreach (var frame in dte.Debugger.CurrentThread.StackFrames.Cast<EnvDTE.StackFrame>())
    ...
```

If you wish to modify the current thread/stack or get more details than EnvDTE exposes, this is also possible but non-trivial. There is a COM interface called `IDebuggerInternal` that exposes these things directly, but it's not exported from the public MS DLLs. However, since it's a COM interface, you can re-declare it in C# and cast the `SVsShellDebugger` instance to it. If you want to go down this route I suggest disassembling Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.Internal, Version=11.0.0.0 (e.g. with dotPeek) to get the interface definition and GUID.

Comment: Got it running! :) https://ibb.co/qC1jVmL
Thank you once more for your help.  I haven't hooked into that event yet.  Instead, I run my extension manually when a breakpoint is hit.  Getting it to work with events is next.