# Visual Studio Extension capturing event before stopping the Debug Process ( IVsDebugProcessNotify BeforeStopDebuggingProcess)

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, visual-studio-addins, vs-extensibility

I am currently experimenting with Visual Studio Extensions.
I need to subscribe to an event that gets called before the actual Debugger is stopped.
Basically I am just Attaching to Managed Process (not running via F5). The problem is that Stop Debugging simply "detaches" the process, and the process continues running after that.
I plan to use this event to notify our process to exit

I have a class that implements `IDebugEventCallback2`, `IVsDebuggerEvents` and `IVsDebugProcessNotify`.

```
class MyDebugger : IDebugEventCallback2, IVsDebuggerEvents, IVsDebugProcessNotify
```

Inside this class, there is a member that subscribes to Debugger Events using `IVsDebugger`'s `AdviseDebugEventCallback()` and `AdviseDebuggerEvents()` events.

```
_debugger = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsShellDebugger)) as IVsDebugger;
if (_debugger != null)
{
    _debugger.AdviseDebugEventCallback(this);
    _debugger.AdviseDebuggerEvents(this, out _debuggerEventsCookie);
}
```

I noticed however that the events fired from `AdviseDebugEventCallback`'s Event() handler does not always gets called before the actual Stop Debugging (next few lines after the breakpoint are still executed after I clicked Stopped Debugging). Around 4 or out of 5 times, the event from `IDebugCustomEvent110` (riidEvent of 2615D9BC-1948-4D21-81EE-7A963F20CF59) gets called before any line from the attached process gets further executed. I still have to digest the details of the events fired in the Event() handler, but looking at the breakpoints, seems like I could not rely on this as it only works as per my expectation around 4 out of 5 times.

I am currently looking at the `BeforeStopDebuggingProcess()` method inside `IVsDebugProcessNotify`.
However, I don't know how to "Subscribe" or "Advice" from this interface.
Any advice how? There isn't much Google result about this topic.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found something hacky, please comment if this is recommended or not.
I got some hint about the `CommandEvents` from this post:
[How do I know from my VSIX that a build will be followed by a Debug session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865333/how-do-i-know-from-my-vsix-that-a-build-will-be-followed-by-a-debug-session)

First, I subscribed to the commandEvents of DTE.

```
DTE dte = await serviceProvider.GetServiceAsync(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
if (dte != null)
{
    events = dte.Events;
    commandEvents = events.CommandEvents;
    commandEvents.BeforeExecute += OnBeforeExecute;
}
```

Then, inside `OnBeforeExecute`, I am hardcoding this particular GUID and ID which I observed to be fired whenever Stop Debugging is clicked (amongst many other events).
If I put `Thread.Sleep()` of 30 seconds inside this handler, the Stop Button of the Visual Studio freezes for 30 seconds (eventually the entire Visual Studio) :-) The code will resume after 30 seconds of wait.

```
private void OnBeforeExecute(string Guid, int ID, object CustomIn, object CustomOut, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
    if (Guid == "{5EFC7975-14BC-11CF-9B2B-00AA00573819}" && ID == 179)
    {
        // Stop command is detected
        Trace.WriteLine($"[OnBeforeExecute] {Guid} --- {ID} Stop Command Detected");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use `EnvDTE.DebuggerEvents.OnEnterDesignMode`, though I don't know if it fires too late for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Cameron thank you for  answer. OnEnterDesignMode fires too late for my scenario though. I just used the workaround I posted above.